# Overwriting specific cells in netcdf

Tags: python, netcdf, nco, cdo-climate

Is there a netcdf operator (from nco or any python netcdf library) which can be used to overwrite specific cells in a netcdf file?

I want to change the values of a small region in a netcdf file containing global climate data. 
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy with [netCDF4-python](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/). For example, suppose `nc` is your netCDF file, the variable is named `var`, and the index of the cell you want to change is `(0,0,0)`. Then:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
new_value = -999
nc.variables['var'][0,0,0] = new_value
```

netCDF4 represents all netCDF arrays using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), which enables their powerful manipulation using numpy's [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and other capabilities.

Answer (score 6):

Or NCO's ncap2 does this in one command with

```
ncap2 -s 'var[0,0,0]=-999' in.nc out.nc
```

ncap2 is described [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#ncap2)

Answer (score 0):

CDO can set a specific lon-lat "rectangular" region to a value, here is the manual example:

To set all values in the region with the longitudes from 120E to 90W and latitudes from 20N to 20S to the constant value -999 use:

```
cdo setclonlatbox,-999,120,-90,20,-20 infile outfile
```